# select: Capybara::Ambiguous: Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching visible option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to select a country from a list. There are indeed 2 items with the same name.

```
select user_info.company_country, from: 'Company country'
```

HTML:

```
<select class="" name="user[company_country]" id="user_company_country">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
... 200+ countries
<option value="United States of America">United States of America</option>
<option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
```

Error:

```
 Capybara::Ambiguous:
   Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching visible option "United States of America" within #<Capybara::Node::Element tag="select" path="/html/body/div[3]/section/div/div/div/form/div/div[8]/select">
```

There doesn't appear to be any options to choose the first option.

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#select-instance_method

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As usual with Capybara there are multiple ways to do what you want. You should be able to do it by manually finding the option you want and then calling `select_option` on it

```
find('#user_company_country option[value="United States of America"]', match: :first).select_option
```

or

```
first(:option, 'United States of America').select_option
```

or possibly by passing the `match: :first` option to select (haven't actually tried that, but from the code it should work since the options are shared between the two finds `select` actually performs)

```
select user_info.company_country, from: 'Company country', match: :first
```

Comment: Wow thanks I was about to edit and say `first("option[value='#{user_info.company_country}']").click` did not work. (It would not actually select the country or submit.)  But `first("option[value='#{user_info.company_country}']").select_option` worked!

Comment: `select user_info.company_country, from: 'Company country', match: :first` did work too. Though I have reservations about using undocumented features.

Comment: @Chloe feel free to use it,  I won’t be changing that